Filling complement set in Eulero-Venn diagrams (Tikz)
Well I'm stuck on this, perhaps stupid, part of drawing Euler-Venn diagrams.
Here is my work so far: I was trying to draw the various diagrams, but I got stuck in filling the complement set.
This is the main preamble:
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrreport}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={173mm, 257mm}, margin=17mm}

\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{enumitem, xcolor, cleveref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{pspicture}

This is for example the symmetric difference
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\colorlet{circle edge}{blue!41}
\colorlet{circle area}{green!11}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}

\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[filled, even odd rule] \firstcircle node {$A$}
                             \secondcircle node{$B$};
\node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$A \triangle B$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Here is all ok, as well it is for the other diagrams. Now the complement:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=green!11]
\scope
\fill (-2, 2) rectangle (-2,0);
\endscope
\draw (0,0) circle (1) (0,1)  node [text=black,above] {$A$}
  (-2,-2) rectangle (3,2) node [text=black,above] {$U$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


I am stuck on how to fill the $A^c$ set only... Thank you for the help.

Please have a look here for construction of MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimal-working-example-mwe

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[pink] (-2,-2) rectangle (3,2) (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=1] (0,1) node [above] {$A$};
\draw (-2,-2) rectangle (3,2) node[above] {$U$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



My deepest thankfulness.
